# String join() method used with for loop

Tags: python, join, int

I need your help, because I don't understand why is possible to use the `join()` method with a `for`loop as an argument.

Ex:

```
" ".join(str(x) for x in list)
```

Python Documentation:

> `str.join(iterable)`
>   Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable.
>
> A `TypeError` will be raised if there are any non-string values in iterable, including bytes objects. The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

Can please somebody explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement `(str(x) for x in list)` is called a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
>>> (str(x) for x in [1,2,3])
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fc916f01d20>
```

What this does is create an object that can be iterated over exactly once, and yields elements that would be created one at a time. You can iterate over it as you would a list, like this:

```
>>> gen = (str(x) for x in [1,2,3])
>>> for s in gen:
...     print s
... 
1
2
3
```

A generator expression is iterable, so what the join function does is iterate over it and join its values.

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes sense :)